# <s:iterator> Displaying three names in each row

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator

Here i am iterating over a searched user list which is working properly.
I am trying to  display three  user in each row
like

```
u1   u2   u3
u4   u5   u6
     ..
     ..
```

This code  showing one username in each row. i have to show as above

```
<s:iterator var="searchedUser" value="searchedUserList">
    <tr><td>
       <s:property value="UserName"/>
    </td></tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve it? You can put html tags inside `<s:iterator>` like `<tr>` if you didn't know yet.

Comment: It's putting a user per row because you put each user in a row.

Comment: Yes how to write <s:property>

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV Doesn't matter, these aren't inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code:

```
<table>
    <s:iterator value="{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}" status="status">
        <s:if test="%{#status.index == 0}"><tr><td><s:property /></td></s:if>
            <s:elseif test="%{#status.index%3 == 0}">
            </tr><tr><td><s:property /></td>
            </s:elseif>
            <s:else>
                <td><s:property /></td>
            </s:else>
        </s:iterator>
    </tr>
</table>
```